# Is it possible to use same OG action on 3 or more OG object?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

We use some defualt og object, like articles, books, profiles, and so on. Is it possible to create a  same og action for all of them ?

For example , I'd like my own copychanges on it:

"Ildiko **liked** XY **topic** on this site",
 or "Ildiko **liked** James **profile** on the site "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, thats not currently possible.

You can have "{user} {action'd} {object} on {appname}" in the title. if you want to add context to that story, you can use Object References or Action References to link the action or object to another object. Details of this referenced object can then be displayed in the story attachment, below the story title.